# Scaling a spritesheet in CSS

Tags: css

I'm having an issue where as soon as I use the background-size property, it seems to reduce the size of the background rather than increase it.

```
div.someelement{
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    background: url('spritesheet.png') no-repeat;
        background-size: 200% 200%;
        background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I'd expect background-size: 200% 200% to double the scale of the spritesheet. The element in the spritesheet is actually 100px per 110px, and I'm trying to scale it down to this 50x55 box. What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve that?

I also don't care about IE8 compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your image is larger than 100px.

If the div is 50px, and you set the bakcground size to be 200%, it means 200% of 50px, so your background will have a size of 100px.

If the native size of the image is bigger, then you are shrinking it. Not making it twice bigger.

Answer (score 0):

If the box and the image have the same ration then use `background-size:cover;` or `background-size:contain;`

---

***Update after comments***

When using percentage values in background size, it is based on the dimensions of the element it is applied. So `200%` on a `50px` element will make the background image be `100px`.

In you case you are better off using actual pixels, and since you want the background to be half its original size just set it to

```
div.someelement{
    /*.. other properties ..*/
    background-size: 262px 225.5px;
    /*.. other properties ..*/
}
```

Comment: Neither of these options seem to do anything I want the thing to do.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/meyZa I want to scale up the sprite sheet, not make it small like it is the case with cover and contain.

Comment: @Sefam can you explain a bit more what you want to do, then ? Are you showing part of the image in the element ? In general the `%` value in `background-size` refers to the available area in the element it is applied.

Comment: The spritesheet is 524x451 pixels. There is an element inside that is exactly 100x110 pixels. I want to show only this element in a box that is 50x55 pixels as shown in the first post. I am unable to scale the spritesheet in such a way where I can show the entirety of the 100x110 sprite in the 50x55 pixels box. Is that specific enough?

Comment: So it *resizes* the image in regards to the elements dimensions. It might be easier, in this case,  if you set its size in pixels. In your case for that element set `background-size: 262px 225.5px;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a 524x451 size image in its original size, you need to count its scale/size based on the div's size, which will, in your case, be 524/50 = 10.48 (1048%) for its width.

And then, to make the 100x110 fit inside a 50x55 sized div, it has to be half of 1048, 524 (and using the same math for its height will give you 410).

```css
div {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdDOg.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 524% 410%;
  background-position: -50px -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 55px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```